# Direct Command acr122u on mac nfc

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard

I am trying to establish NFC connection using `javax.smartcardio`. I can successfully run this code on Windows but I couldn't make it work on Mac. Seems the problem is the drivers of Mac but I would like to know if there is a solution or not.

```
TerminalFactory factory;
factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
CardTerminal terminal = factory.terminals().list().get(0);
card = terminal.connect("direct");`
```

**Note**: I have to use ***direct*** command.

**Edit:** Why I have to use ***direct*** command is I need to send **APDU** commands when no card is presented. In other protocols like T=0, T=1 I cannot send APDU commands to the reader when there is no card (or device) on the reader.

Comment: Could you point to documentation where this `"direct"` ***protocol*** is specified? It may be that you need a proprietary security provider to use this protocol.

Comment: This looks undocumented. On the other hand, there are some examples that use this protocol ( I also have one that works on only Windows :) )

Comment: I think there is a single way how to accomplish this: register a provider that supplies your own Terminal implementations (to be able to use the `getDefault()` method. Then implement the `"direct"` protocol within the returned `Terminal`. If I remember correctly, `javax.smartcardio` can be extended by a `Provider`.

Answer (score 1):

That's very interesting that you have to use the `"direct"` command - well, you say command but actually it is the transport protocol string. Unfortunately the API says otherwise (checked up to Java 7 SE).

This is an excerpt from the JavaDoc of the `connect(String)` method:

> `protocol` - the protocol to use (`"T=0"`, `"T=1"`, or `"T=CL"`), or `"*"` to connect using any available protocol.

If unsure, I would opt for `"T=1"`, it should be compatible with modern cards and most PCSC readers.

Comment: I'm sure that other readers support these T=* protocols, but my reader's auto-polling mechanism is not compatible for peer-to-peer connections (tested with Android 4.0+) so I need to implement my own one. I can only do this with direct protocol.

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand now: direct talks to the card reader using proprietary reader commands. An interesting but not that portable idea.